# Javascript object options: function or null

Tags: javascript, function, object

This question has probably been asked before, but I don't really know the proper keywords to find a solution on Google, so all my researches returned `0` :) Or better, all my researches ended up with "optional parameters" but for functions.

Let's assume I have this class:

```
var Class = function (params) {
    // I get the data somehow
    params.name(data);
}
```

The problem is that not every time I instantiate `new Class()` I need also to set `name()` like:

```
new Class({
    name: function (data) {
        // Do something with the data
    }
    ... other params ...
})
```

But, with the above syntax, if I don't declare name parameter as a function, an error `params.name is not a function` is thrown:

```
// Error
new Class({
    ... other params ...
})
```

My question is: is there a way to set `params.name()` as an optional parameter (in the object) that can be a function or completely not exist (e.g. `null`)? Something like saying: "when you instantiate the class:

- if you declare `name: function (data) {}` => then: `params.name(data)` is a function
- if you skip `name` => it's anyway ok (no error is thrown)"

Answer (score 3):

In ES6, You can use [default function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) option, like

```js
var Class = function(params = {
  name: (x) => x
}) {
  // I get the data somehow
  data='value';
  params.name(data);
}

Class();
Class({name: x => console.log(x)});
```

Hope this will help!

**EDIT**

Yes @brigo, you are right, sorry I overlooked that point. We are actually looking for nested default rather. A possible solution could be to destructure the object inside the function like

```js
var Class = function(params = {}) {
  // I get the data somehow
  data = 'value';
  withDefaultParams = {
    name: (x) => x,
    ...params
  }
  withDefaultParams.name(data);
}

Class();
Class({
  name: x => console.log('non-default')
});
Class({
  others: x => console.log('non-default')
});
```

Comment: This would be the best solution if only the functionalities of default parameters would work also "against" the object's items. *Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed*. But `name`, in this case, is not directly a parameter (`params` is the parameter) so, if not provided (= it's `undefined`), calling `Class({})` will throw the same error `params.name is not a function`.

Comment: @Brigo, yes you are right, I have overlooked that flow. I have updated the answer, may not be the best but a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you could do something like

```
if (typeof param.name === 'function') {
    param.name(data);
} else {
    // dont do anything or do something different
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a shortener, cleaner and integrated solution (as @Pransun Pal's one could have been) but, at the moment, as you suggested this remains the only one I know

Comment: @Brigo: I posted a different approach below. Maybe that's whar you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery is an option, you could use its `extend` method ([API docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)) like in the following example:

```
var Class = function(params) {

  var _defaults = {
      name: function(){},
      some: 'other stuff'
  };

  params = jQuery.extend(_defaults,params);

  // I get the data somehow
  data='value';
  params.name(data);
}

Class();
Class({foo:'bar'});
Class({name: console.log });
```